# Cómo extraer todos los registros de una tabla Mysql en JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, java-swing, java-8, mysqldb

Estoy tratando de obtener todos los registros de una tabla en mysql llamada tipo_articulo, actualmente hay 6 registros en esa tabla, el problema es que al intentar mostrar esos datos, solo se muestra el ultimo registro. Estoy apenas aprendiendo a programar en JAVA y no se exactamente en donde esta la falla.

Este es el codigo de mi función Listar() que se encuentra en la clase Tipo_ArticuloModel:

```
 public String [] Listar()
{ 
String[] registros = new String[2];
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM tipo_articulo";
 try {
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sSQL);

        while (rs.next()) {
            registros[0] = rs.getString("id");
            registros[1] = rs.getString("nombre");
        }
        return registros;  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
       return null;
    }
}
```

y este es el código donde se muestran los datos. Esto se hace en la clase Tipo_ArticuloView (Es un JFrame). Lo que se hace aqui es que, al presionar el botón Mostrar Registros, se deberian mostrar todos los registros que tiene la tabla, el problema es que solo se me muestra uno.

```
 private void btnMostrarRegistrosActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   

        String [] Resultados = new String[2];
        Tipo_ArticuloModel Db_ListarTipoArt;
        Db_ListarTipoArt = new Tipo_ArticuloModel();

        Resultados = Db_ListarTipoArt.Listar();

        System.out.print(Resultados[0] + " -> " + Resultados[1]);

}
```

Soy bastante nuevo en esto de programar en JAVA y no se exactamente como mostrar todos los registros, no solo el ultimo de la tabla. Alguna ayuda o recomendación que puedan darme?

Comment: Esos datos quieres mostrar en una tabla no?

Comment: como estoy iniciando quería probar primero mostrandolos de forma bastante sencilla con un system.out.print, solo por prueba, pero al final si deseo mostrarlos en una Tabla, solo que aun no se cómo hacerlo. Yo ya tengo una tabla en el JFrame pero aun no la uso.

Comment: Te recomendaria que utilices un ORM hibernate. De tal manera solo uses objectos desde Java para guardalo usando JPA, hacer query de plano no es bueno, pero si quieres continuar haciendo esto entonces dime cual es el error que te sale o que necesitas?

Comment: Gracias por las recomendaciones, definitivamente investigare sobre ello. El problema que planteaba era que la consulta que realizo a la tabla mysql no me devuelve todos los registros, solo el ultimo registro de la tabla es mostrado. Solo queria saber cómo puedo extraer todos los registro de la tabla para mostrarlos.

Comment: Ta entiendo que quieres hacer. Ahora subo la solución a tu problema que basicamente solo es agregar a una lista lo que haz recibido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno basado que tu quieres obtener todos los registros de ´tipo_articulo´ entonces deberias guardar cada registro a una lista para luego usarlas en el metodo que quieres ver.

```
public List<String[]> Listar() { 
List<String[]> tipoArticulos = new ArrayList<>();

sSQL = "SELECT * FROM tipo_articulo";
 try {
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sSQL);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String[] registros = new String[2];
            registros[0] = rs.getString("id");
            registros[1] = rs.getString("nombre");
            tipoArticulos.add(registros);
        }
        return tipoArticulos;  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
       return null;
    }
}
```

y en el otro metodo seria:

```
 private void btnMostrarRegistrosActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   

        Tipo_ArticuloModel Db_ListarTipoArt;
        Db_ListarTipoArt = new Tipo_ArticuloModel();

        List<String[]> resultado = Db_ListarTipoArt.Listar();

        System.out.print(resultado);
        for (String[] data : resultado) {
             System.out.print(data[0] + " , " + data[1]);
        }    
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Lo he probado, lo que me arroja en la salida es esto: [[Ljava.lang.String;@1f961ca, [Ljava.lang.String;@3d720b, [Ljava.lang.String;@89a87f, [Ljava.lang.String;@af7f9c, [Ljava.lang.String;@1cb932, [Ljava.lang.String;@10436d0]

Comment: esta bien ahi obtenienes a los datos si quieres ver mas detalles de cada dato lo haces un bucle para ver cada dato, entoncesahora lo actualizo la respuesta.

Comment: @MarcosSchmell he actualizado la respuesta puedes verlo ahora con mas detalle separado por una coma, si esto ha resuelto tu pregunta, entonces aceptalo como respuesta. gracias.l

Comment: Listo, Funcionando! Muchas Gracias